# Smartbind date format and error in R

Tags: r, date, append

I'm getting an error using smartbind to append two datasets. First, I'm pretty sure the error I'm getting:

```
> Error in as.vector(x, mode) : invalid 'mode' argument
```

is coming from the date variable in both datasets. The date variable in it's raw format is such: month/day/year. I transformed the variable after importing the data using as.Date and format

```
> rs.month$xdeeddt <- as.Date(rs.month$xdeeddt, "%m/%d/%Y")
> rs.month$deed.year <-  as.numeric(format(rs.month$xdeeddt, format = "%Y"))
> rs.month$deed.day <-  as.numeric(format(rs.month$xdeeddt, format = "%d"))
> rs.month$deed.month <-  as.numeric(format(rs.month$xdeeddt, format = "%m"))
```

The resulting date variable is as such:

```
> [1] "2014-03-01" "2014-03-13" "2014-01-09" "2013-10-09"
```

The transformation for the date was applied to both datasets (the format of the raw data was identical for both datasets). When I try to use smartbind, from the gtools package, to append the two datasets it returns with the error above. I removed the date, month, day, and year variables from both datasets and was able to append the datasets successfully with smartbind.

Any suggestions on how I can append the datasets with the date variables.....?

Comment: What version of `gtools` are you running? I see to see that error in `gtools_3.1.1` but not `gtools_3.4.1`

Comment: I have version 3.0.0, I'll update and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came here after googling for the same error message during a smartbind of two data frames.  The discussion above, while not so conclusive about a solution, definitely helped me move through this error.

Both my data frames contain POSIXct date objects.  Those are just a numeric vector of UNIXy seconds-since-epoch, along with a couple of attributes that provide the structure needed to interpret the vector as a date object.  The solution is simply to strip the attributes from that variable, perform the smartbind, and then restore the attributes:

```
these.atts <- attributes(df1$date)
attributes(df1$date) <- NULL
attributes(df2$date) <- NULL
df1 <- smartbind(df1,df2)
attributes(df1$date) <- these.atts
```

I hope this helps someone, sometime.

-Andy